# Parse xml tag value which is in next line with python

Tags: python, xml

```
<type>
War, Thriller
</type>
```

I have a XML file which has above data, like Value of Tag **type** is in next line. When I read the data with the sax I am not getting value of tag **type**. May I know how read the value? I have used the example code in [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_xml_processing.htm)

```
<Details shelf="Employee details"> 
<employee name="Enemy Behind">
 <type> War, Thriller </type>
 <format>DVD</format>
 <year>2003</year>
 <rating>PG</rating>
 <stars>10</stars>
 <description>Talk about a US-Japan war</description>
 </employee>
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. You can add more details to your question by using the [edit] button. XML can be formatted by using the `code sample` button. I have added the code for you.

Comment: Please include the minimal code you're trying and what you get instead of the expected value.